# How was まで used in this sentence: やる気がない者に構ってやるのは義務教育まで

Tags: grammar, particle-まで, cleft-sentences

I was wondering how まで was used in this sentence:

> やる気がない者に　構ってやるのは 義務教育まで→ 意志なき者は去るほかない

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13201/9831

Comment: Please don't try to answer questions in the comment section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [童貞が許されるのは小学生までだよね - translation of まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/%e7%ab%a5%e8%b2%9e%e3%81%8c%e8%a8%b1%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af%e5%b0%8f%e5%ad%a6%e7%94%9f%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7%e3%81%a0%e3%82%88%e3%81%ad-translation-of-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7)

Answer (score 1):

It's a particle that means "until ～". 義務教育まで just means "until compulsory education".

> やる気がない者に構ってやるのは義務教育まで(だ)。
> It's only until compulsory education that I care about people who aren't willing to do it.

If you still have trouble parsing this sentence, check the [grammar of cleft sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) (aka ～のは～だ construction).